# NetBeans & Git: Correct Way to Sync Sub-Folder Only to Remote Server?

Tags: wordpress, git, netbeans

I'm doing PHP development on a Wordpress child theme. I'm using the NetBeans IDE, and its Git options for version control. I don't want to push the whole project to the remote server that hosts the site, because the project contains all of Wordpress. If possible, I just want to sync the project sub-folder that contains the Wordpress child theme.

Is it okay to do this, and if so, what is the correct procedure?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git requires you to add exactly what you push, every time.

So its always-opt in. All you have to do is only add the specific subfolder, and you are set. If you want you can put everything else in a `.gitignore` file.